# Spark 2.1 register UDF to functionRegistry

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-2.0

Hi I want to register a UDF object that is already created.  I'm using spark 2.1, and the sparkSession.udf.register() function does not accept a UDF parameter only a regular scala function.  It's easy to miss something from the large Spark API so just asking is there a function or constructor that will allow this in 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd reverse the the problem and use udf registration to get `UserDefinedFunction`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

val id: UserDefinedFunction = spark.udf.register("id", (x: Int) => x)
```

Which would work both in `DataFrames`:

```
val id: UserDefinedFunction = spark.udf.register("id", (x: Int) => x)
```

and SQL:

```
spark.sql("SELECT id(id) FROM RANGE(42)")
```